# I need help to understand why a function call reverted without any reason

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I have a Registry contract, which holds addresses of different smart contracts. The registry has getter for every contract address it holds.

In other contract at some point I need to retrieve one of the addresses.

When I call the getter function at the beginning of function it works properly.

When I call it after two computed hashes, it just reverts without any reason provided.

There is still a lot of gas left, so not out of gas problem for sure.

Don’t know if it’s  about stack overflow , because stack frames are pushed for every function call.

**Update** for @RickPark questions

Computated hashes is 2 times calculation of

```
hash = keccak256(
  abi.encodePacked(
    abi.encodePacked(...someParams),
    abi.encodePacked(...moreParams)
  )
)
```

Getters works like this

```
contract Registry is Ownable {
  address core;

  function setCore(address _core) external onlyOwner {
    core = _core;
  }

  function getCore() public view returns (address) {
    return core;
  }
}
```

and called as

`Core(registry.getCore()).doSomething()`

My function basically gets 3 structs (experimental ABI v2) and makes those 2 hashes and few more validations.
So part of some validations are exactly calling the Core, but before we need to get its address.

If I get address before hashes, it works, after hashes it reverts without any reason.

**Update 2** for @RickPark questions

```
contract LoosingHope is LibOrder, LibSomeStruct, Ownable {
  Registry internal registry;

  function setRegistry(address _registry) external onlyOwner {
    registry = Registry(_registry);
  }

  function create(Order memory _buyOrder, Order memory _sellOrder, SomeStruct memory _someStruct) public {
      require(
          _buyOrder.something == _sellOrder.something &&
          _sellOrder.something == 0,
          "MATCH:NOT_CREATION"
      );

      // Validate taker if set
      validateTakerAddress(_buyOrder, _sellOrder);
      validateTakerAddress(_sellOrder, _buyOrder);

      // Validate sender if set
      validateSenderAddress(_buyOrder);
      validateSenderAddress(_sellOrder);

      // Validate expiration if set
      validateExpiration(_buyOrder);
      validateExpiration(_sellOrder);

      // Validate if was canceled
      // orderHashes[0] - buyOrderHash
      // orderHashes[1] - sellOrderHash
      bytes32[2] orderHashes;
      orderHashes[0] = hashOrder(_buyOrder);
      validateCanceled(orderHashes[0]);

      // registry.getCore(); <------------ doesn't reverts here

      orderHashes[1] = hashOrder(_sellOrder);

      registry.getCore(); <------------ reverts here

      validateCanceled(orderHashes[1]);
  }
}
```

**Update 3** for @RickPark questions

Registry is simple Ownable contract with setter and getter of Core address. Setting the address is following by onlyOwner modifier, getting is public for anyone. It's initialised by me as well, I use it as Registry for addresses, so contracts are able to communicate with each other.

**Update 4** for @RickPark questions

Environment

- OS: MacOs
- Solc: v0.4.24

Networks:
*all of them fail*

- Truffle JSONRPC
- Ganache - all latest versions
- Rinkeby
- Kovan

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90682/discussion-on-question-by-ali-run-function-call-reverted-without-any-reason).

Comment: Reopen this, please. It has been extensively edited as requested.

Answer (score 1):

As resulting by the comments, we had a detailed check of the code. The final solution has been to suppose a compiler bug in a wide sense, for instance lacking of warning about possibly unsupported features.

Switching to compiler more recent solved the problem (0.5.x) without code modifications but those needed by the new release of the compiler.